# Ionic Search input in header bar

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I do not understand why the input text is slightly offset to bottom when rendered in IOS simulator and in Browser is positioned right.

The code is very simple:

```
<ion-nav-title>
    <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input ng-model="search_text" type="text" placeholder="Search..." focus-me my-enter="search_model(search_text)" autofocus>
        </label>
    </div>
</ion-nav-title>
```

Here I attach two snapshots (in browser and in IOS simulator):

[image: Browser]
[image: IOS Simulator]

What's hapenning?

Comment: I have the same issue, do you fixed it ?

Comment: have you take  alook to this? https://github.com/djett41/ionic-filter-bar

Answer (score 1):

The header-bar shouldn't be inside a ion-nav-title. Actually if you use a div with class="bar header-bar" you could declare a title inside using class="title". For example:

```
<div class="bar bar-header bar-light">
  <h1 class="title">bar-light</h1>
</div>
```

Removing the ion-nav-title tag should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the ion-nav-title to ion-nav-bar